# Pandas: speed up dataframe column conversion?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make an utility function that allows me to convert columns of a generic Pandas DF based on some column specifications metadata.

````py
def convert_pandas_columns(df: pd.DataFrame, metadata: dict | None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Convert a pandas DataFrame `df` columns starting from a metadata dict `cols`:
    ```
    {
      "columns": {
        "col1": {
            "type": "str"
        },
        "col2": {
            "type": "datetime"
        },
        "col3": {
            "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
    ```
    """

    if metadata is None or 'columns' not in metadata:
        # Skip conversion if no metadata is available
        return df

    mappings = {
        'str': lambda x: x.astype(str, errors='ignore'),
        'int': lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='integer', errors='coerce'),
        'float': lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='float', errors='coerce'),
        'bool': lambda x: x.astype(bool, errors='ignore'),
        'datetime': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'),
        'list': lambda x: json.loads(x) if x else [],  # always expect a json object
    }

    dtypes = {}
    for k, v in metadata['columns'].items():
        pd_type = mappings.get(v['type'], None)
        if pd_type is not None:
            dtypes[k] = pd_type

    return df.transform(
        {
            **{
                column: lambda x: x
                for column in df.columns
            },
            **dtypes,
        },
    )
````

This works but it's extremely slow. Is there anything I could change to improve its performance? Previously I was using the `astype` function but it's not as flexible as this approach.

Comment: Do you know why it's so slow? Maybe it could be faster if you applied transformations in place?

Comment: Not really. I was asking looking for some clues for this reason. Is it even possible to transform in place?

Comment: Do you really need the identity mapping for untouched columns?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html# btw?

Comment: @Learningisamess if I don't I'm losing that column during `transform`. I think that `convert_dtypes` is not leaving me much flexibility since it's all inferred.

Comment: My bad, I had this method in mind actually https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html seems like it can take a dictionary of mappings too

Comment: @Learningisamess yes that's the alternative I was using as I stated at the end of the question. The problem with that is that I cannot use way better/improved conversion like `to_datetime`, `to_numeric` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transform your dataframe in place, you can use:

```
def convert_pandas_columns(df: pd.DataFrame, metadata: dict | None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Convert a pandas DataFrame `df` columns starting from a metadata dict `cols`:
    """

    if metadata is None or 'columns' not in metadata:
        # Skip conversion if no metadata is available
        return df

    mappings = {
        'str': lambda x: x.astype(str, errors='ignore'),
        'int': lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='integer', errors='coerce'),
        'float': lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='float', errors='coerce'),
        'bool': lambda x: x.astype(bool, errors='ignore'),
        'datetime': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'),
        'list': lambda x: json.loads(x) if x else [],  # always expect a json object
    }

    def create_apply_map(functions):
      def f(col):
          return functions[col.name](col)
      return f

    dtypes = {}
    for k, v in metadata['columns'].items():
        pd_type = mappings.get(v['type'], None)
        if pd_type is not None:
            dtypes[k] = convert_func
    return df.apply(create_apply_map(dtypes))
```

Output:

```
# sample
>>> df
    col1       col2  col3  col4
0  hello 2023-06-08   3.0  12.2
1  world 2023-06-09   5.0   4.3

# before
>>> df.dtypes
col1     object
col2     object
col3     object
col4    float64
dtype: object

# after
>>> df.dtypes
col1            object
col2    datetime64[ns]
col3           float32
col4           float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This actually speeded up the conversion! I'm wondering now if there's a way to parallelize the conversions (I'm not sure but I think `astype` does it). Because now I'm doing them one at a time

Comment: I've submitted a modification to your answer that is exploiting the `apply` function that should parallelize the conversions instead of doing inplace for each column.

Comment: `apply` is a for loop, I don't think that speeds up the process? Have you noticed a significant improvement (before accepting your edit)?

Comment: I saw a little speed up ye (didn't got into much details tho). The apply is maybe cleaner anyway? Idk

Comment: Ok. I will accept your improvement. Honestly I prefer your original code :)